# How to fix strange backspace behaviour with urxvt + zsh?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, zsh

I use urxvt in combination with zsh. However since my fresh install of ubuntu 10.04 I have the following problem. If I type backspace the cursor moves to the right (instead of deleting the characters on the left).

Suppose I typed n characters then pressing backspace n-times moves the cursor n- positions to the left, if I type backspace then one more, the cursor doesn't move anymore.

If I type the left arrow, nothing happens, if I type the right arrow *afterwards* a some character occurs.

```
mv .zshrc .zshrc.bak
mv .Xdefaults .Xdefaults.bak
```

didn't help.

urxvt + bash works fine as well as xterm + zsh.

zsh-version: 4.3.11-4ubuntu2.is.3ubuntu1
rxvt-unicode version: 9.09-3

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .zshrc:

```
TERM=xterm
```

Comment: This fixed it for me FWIW.

Comment: Better use `TERM=xterm-256color` to support 256 color.

Comment: Aren't you just avoiding the problem, by using xterm instead of urxvt?

Comment: Yes, this worked for me as well. I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) with Ubuntu and ZSH and it's been annoying me for so long. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 8):

In zsh, what does `bindkey | grep delete` say? These are the lines I get:

```
"^D" delete-char-or-list
"^H" backward-delete-char
"^[3;5~" delete-char
"^[[3~" delete-char
"^?" backward-delete-char
```

You should have "^?" as that represents backspace. If not... you can call `bindkey "^?" backward-delete-char` at the zsh prompt to put it in.

Does that resolve the problem?

Comment: bindkey | grep delete                                                                                                  
"^D" delete-char-or-list
"^?" backward-delete-char

Answer (score 1):

You could also get around the problem by setting

`stty erase '^?'`

Here are some details about the deviant behavior of certain terminal emulators (which is by the way why certain emulators have this problem): [Linux Backspace/Delete mini-HOWTO](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/BackspaceDelete.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thread and perhaps no-one will see this, but the issue for me was in the `.Xresources` file. I had misinterpreted the `URxvt*termName` parameter as the string that would become the `urxvt` window title. It is in fact what becomes the `$TERM` environment variable, unless the shell overrides it (`bash` does).

My solution was to add `URxvt*termName: xterm-256color` to the `~/.Xresources` file. As with any change to this file, you will need to run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` and completely restart `urxvt` (including `urxvtd` daemon processes) for the changes to show.